# In what class or textbook is Fisher Information taught?

Tags: statistics, fisher-information

I have understood and worked problems in all the contents of Wackerly's *Mathematical Statistics With Applications* 7th edition. In trying to work in other statistics courses, they all seem to assume I have already learned Fisher Information.  In what class or textbook would I learn about it? Repeated searches on Google and here turned up nothing. I have bought multiple textbooks on statistics and they either don't mention it or assume I already know it.

In general, I'm struggling to understand the statistics curriculum; different classes seem to have almost a random assortment of topics: sampling, Bayesian inference, a dozen flavors of biostatistics all seemingly different, and so on.  What text would you recommend to advance my understanding?  I feel as if I have mastered "Stats 101" and I am looking for "Stats 102" so to speak.  I would like to be able to understand (and tutor) statistics at a higher level than "blind plug and chug" aka "statistics as flowchart."

Comment: My first hit on Google: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

Comment: Fair to say there seems to be a lot going on in statistics departments these days!

Comment: I first learned about it in a graduate level econometrics course, probably appears earlier during undergrad in a pure statistics course of study.

Comment: Casella and Berger's "Statistical Inference" and Keener's "Theoretical Statistics" discuss it. It is usually brought up when introducing the Cramér-Rao bound.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMorfe, I already found and read that.  I was asking where a student is SUPPOSED to learn it.  Which is important because context matters, and I don't know which of the details I'm supposed to have at my fingertips.

Comment: Here it is taught as part of a Statistical Theory II class:
http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/Fisher_info.pdf

Comment: A master's degree program in statistics will typically have a theory-of-statistics course in which Fisher information is dealt with to some extent.